# Move to ConTeXt or clean up existing LaTeX?

Tags: context

Having used TeX StackExchange for quite some time now as a very helpful and comprehensive source only as a reader I finally have to reach out actively to the community for advice: I have a quite big repository of LaTeX files to maintain about 40 different documents of technical documentation. Over the years my predecessor wrote several packages, some in TeX, some in LaTeX, and the preamble has grown tremendously.

Here is the background information summed up:

- technical documentation of about 40 different documents
- currently using XeLaTeX as engine
- preamble currently includes around 60 packages
- length of the final PDFs is between 7 to 300 pages
- some documents are only in English, some in up to 16 languages, including Chinese
- using TikZ for layout in some parts
- total of almost 900 tex files

Since I am experiencing increasing trouble with incompatibilities, and I am incapable of understanding a lot of what has been written in the packages and the preamble, I have reached a point where I would like to start anew.

I have read several posts here on ConTeXt and LaTeX comparison, but some are rather old (like i.e. [How do LaTeX3 and ConTeXt compare?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29979/how-do-latex3-and-context-compare)) and I would really like to get an idea of the "state of the art", and other posts are quite general or about what to choose when starting from scratch.

So finally, here is my question:

Having experienced many difficulties with packages I am considering switching to ConTeXt. Did anybody carry out such a move in a comparable setup and could share some experiences?

Considering the huge number of tex files that would have to be converted/adapted, the other option is to stick with LaTeX (maybe switching from XeLaTeX to LuaLaTeX as engine?), try to reduce the number of packages and simplify the preamble. Has anybody experiences to share how to proceed best with such a "cleanup" project?

I hope this question is not too subjective, I would very much appreciate to read about experiences and pros and cons for both options.

Comment: It depends heavily on the packages used. If you e.g. specific bibliography styles, you'd be better off  cleaning the LaTeX code. If you want to cleanup things, you could consider writing your own `.cls` and `.sty` files, which contain the necessary code. Having said that: ConTeXt is excellent and if you want to start anew, you could do so using it. Again: all depends on the actual code and wether you think, it's easier rewriting it then maintaining.

Comment: If you have a lot of custom packages and/or existing special purpose packages then moving to ConTeXt may not actually improve your situation (or even make it worse), because you will need to recreate all that functionality somehow. For some functionality you can probably use ConTeXt internals, which will make your code more consistent and reliable, but for other functionality you will have a lot of trouble incorporating it in ConTeXt, while in LaTeX it is already there.

Comment: That said, 60 packages seems excessive, you can probably clean that up a lot, starting with not using the same preamble for each file but choosing only the packages that are needed for a particular file. And then continuing by asking yourself for every package "do I really need this functionality or can I write a clear document without it".

Comment: @DG' Actually the self-written .sty files are causing many of my problems. That is why I would like to reduce them or get rid of them completely, if possible.

Comment: @Marijn Many of the files depend one one another (libraries being imported into several documents; different language versions of the same file...). Furthermore, all the documents use the same layout and have to provide the same functionalities. I don't know if creating different preambles is feasible. However, questioning the necessity of every single package is surely a way to go. The difficulty is where to start.

Comment: Starting with the understanding that the syntax of ConTeXt is very different from that of LaTeX, you might experiment by selecting one "typical" but relatively small file and try to convert it.

Comment: I have done a similar conversion in a little bit smaller scale but radically different: As my source LaTeX files have been a mess, I have translated them to XML with special tags for raw TikZ. These XMLs are processed with ConTeXt (and its XML capabilities as wall as some Lua magic) nowadays. But this conversion only worked, because I could massively reduce the preamble, have done quite a bit content tuning (search and replace; big trade-off) and had not too difficult requirements.

Comment: I switched to ConTeXt some time ago and converted my files with a perl script of my own. Of course I had to learn ConTeXt syntax first, as suggested by @barbara beetton. Conversion went quite easily, but I did not use that many packages: mainly `beamer` `fontspec` `polyglossia`, `menukeys`, `biblatex`. I use metapost now for graphs, but choose not to convert advanced TikZ pictures. If they need small improvements, I don't run them under ConTeXt but compile them as standalone LaTeX documents.